# How to better understand permissions in the Democracy module(fastTrack)

Tags: council, democracy

new to substrate. here are three modules: `Democracy` `Council`, `TechnicalCommittee`. i did some experiments on the local testnet ,but failed.

I know that the proposal under `Democracy` can execute sudo origin. so i did the following:

Democracy -> Submit preimage(system-> set_balance(sudo origin) and get this preimage hash) -> Submit proposal(input preimage hash)

if the proposal enters referenda and voted pass. this set_balance proposal will execute. this process will take a long time.

`Council`, `TechnicalCommittee` can speed up the process. and they all use collective pallet.

i use `techcomm` -> `proposals` -> `Submit proposal`:

```
democracy -> fastTrack(proposalHash is set_balance preimage hash)
```

vote and end time, I click the close button. but i get this error:

```
technicalCommittee.Executed:

{
  Err: BadOrigin
}
```

why?  fastTrack origin is FastTrackOrigin.

```
type FastTrackOrigin =pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, TechnicalCollective, 2, 3>;
```

i use TechnicalCommittee vote this proposal and close(execute) it, why Origin is BadOrigin?

If use `Council` and `TechnicalCommittee`, What the correct process should look like？

BTW,is there any more comprehensive documentation on this?. such as :

https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-governance/

ADD:
If i want to use fast_tack to setBalance, what is the correct way?

Comment: You might want to read up about the proposed changes: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in stating that the [`fast_track` call must have the origin `FastTrackOrigin`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/22d40c761a985482f93bbbea5ba4199bdba74f8e/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L799).

Remember that Polkadot [has `Sudo` removed](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/commit/29fea4e433f1c5e74a3ea8c4237e6af5f65a8217) and fastTrack is something that the technical committee is responsible for so it makes sense that it has to come from the technical committee = [`fastTrackOrigin`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/democracy#fast-track-origin).

You could try adding yourself to the technical committee via the extrinsic `technicalMembership > addMember` then trying again.